# Stackoverflow during protobuf deserialization

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a problem with protobuf-net 2.0.0.668. The following program produces a stack overflow upon deserialisation:

```
[TestFixture]
internal class Program
{
    [Test]
    public void TestSerialize()
    {
        RuntimeTypeModel typeModel = TypeModel.Create();
        typeModel.Add(typeof(ISerializableType), true);
        typeModel[typeof(ISerializableType)].AddSubType(9, typeof(ITechnology));
        MetaType type = typeModel[typeof(ITechnology)].AddSubType(1, typeof(Gsm));
        type.UseConstructor = false;
        type.SetFactory("GetInstance");
        type = typeModel[typeof(ITechnology)].AddSubType(2, typeof(Lte));
        type.UseConstructor = false;
        type.SetFactory("GetInstance");
        typeModel.Add(typeof(Configuration), true);
        typeModel.Freeze();

        var expected = new Configuration { Technology = Gsm.GetInstance() };
        Configuration actual;
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            typeModel.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(mem, expected, typeof(Configuration), PrefixStyle.Fixed32, 0);
            mem.Position = 0;
            actual = (Configuration)typeModel.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix(mem, null, typeof(Configuration), PrefixStyle.Fixed32, 0);
        }

        actual.Technology.Should().BeSameAs(Gsm.GetInstance());
    }
}
```

Using the following entity definitions:

```
public interface ISerializableType
{
}

public interface ITechnology
    : ISerializableType
{
}

public sealed class Gsm
    : ITechnology
{
    private static readonly Gsm Instance = new Gsm();

    private Gsm(){}

    #region Static Methods

    [Pure]
    public static Gsm GetInstance()
    {
        return Instance;
    }

    #endregion
}

public sealed class Lte
    : ITechnology
{
    private static readonly Lte Instance = new Lte();

    #region Static Methods

    [Pure]
    public static Lte GetInstance()
    {
        return Instance;
    }

    #endregion
}

[DataContract]
public sealed class Configuration
{
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public ITechnology Technology;

    public Configuration()
    {
        Technology = new Lte();
    }
}
```

The example does work if I remove the ctor of Configuration or the line "Technology = new Lte();", however I don't understand why this would cause protobuf to enter an endless recursive loop in the first place.

Can somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Interestingly, it doesn't do it if auto-compile is disabled (but: don't do that); I guess it is a bug, then; I will have to investigate what the compile step is screwing up here. Incidentally, I think your configuration is slightly off: I suspect you mean: http://pastie.org/9396277

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Indeed I forgot the "typeModel.Add(typeof(..." for the sub-types while I was writing this small example.